# Populating a listbox from a DataTable and want the highlighted userID to

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

populate a few Textbox like first name.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) //This is how I populate the Listbox from the DT
        {

            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            ListBox1.DataSource = dt;
            ListBox1.DataValueField = "samAccountName"; //column name in DT
            ListBox1.DataBind();
            //FirstBox.Text = 

        }
```

List box code:

```
 <asp:ListBox id="ListBox1" 
       Rows="7"
       Width="100px"
       SelectionMode="Single" 
       runat="server">
  </asp:ListBox>
```

So far I tried to populate the textbox fields (like first Name) from the DT but yea when I highlight another userID in the Listbox, the first name field doesn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the ListBox' [`SelectedIndexChanged event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox.
   string accName = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
   TxtAccountName.Text = accName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got the SelectedIndexChanged event working but the main issue I'm having trouble with is trying to get the values from the DT (example, from the first name column) and filling in the textbox when I highlight a userid.

Comment: @nhat: If i understand you correctly, you only want to show the user of the currently selected item in the TextBox. So why do you need to get him from the DataSource when he's available in the `SelectedItem` of the ListBox?

Comment: Ok I got it, as long as I have the userId I can just make another function to find the userid and the information related to it. Thanks!

Comment: The only value listed in listbox is just the UserId's... Hmm yea I could show all the values in the list box. Thanks for the idea.